# How can I write some tests such that they don't send Email while testing?

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, testing, automated-tests

I am sending an email to user on form submission. I am having issue while testing. I am testing `sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission`, and form submission. But while testing form submission it sends mail every time. And I have a lot of combinations for testing form submission. I am wasting my quota of emails by sending emails while submission testing as I am testing sendEmail function seperately. Can anyone please help me with this.

`SubmitAction` submits the form and sends email. To send email `submitAction` calls `sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission()`.

```
public void sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission(String userId)
    throws EntityDoesNotExistException {

Assumption.assertFalse(ERROR_NULL_PARAMETER, userId == null );

EmailsLogic.sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission(userId);
}
```

I think instead of using above function I should use it like this one  and pass userId = null while testing form submssion ?

```
public void sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission(String userId)
    throws EntityDoesNotExistException {

if (userId != null ) {
    EmailsLogic.sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission(userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: *instead of using above function I should use it like this one and pass `userId = null` while testing form submission?* In that case, it **will** "send email while testing". Which is what I thought you didn't want. Do you want to send the email or not?

Comment: @tarun14110 Abstract the email sending functionality behind it's own service (SRP) and then mock that service for your tests. Using the abstraction allows you to swap between different implementations In production you can then use the production implementation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry, that was my fault. updated. I don't want to send email while submission.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the method that you have for sending emails (`EmailsLogic.sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission`) is a static one.

You can use a library like [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to mock the email service. And in the mock method, you can just print "Email sent", without actually sending an email and test rest of your code.

This is a good article on using PowerMock to test static methods:
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/11/testing-and-mocking-of-static-methods-in-java/

Comment: Static method should not be abused in Java. Instead of using tricks to allow a no testable code to be testable in a tricky way, it would be more interesting to allow the code to be testable in a natural way.
A logic process in a static method is not a good pattern.

Comment: If you have some time, do check the article I linked which makes an argument against your opinion.

Comment: I read. I know and I used PowerMock for a long time. Today, i don't use it anylonger.
In your article, the argument of the author is about testability but using static methods instead of instance methods causes issues not only for testability.
All OOP conception are lost with static method. Passing instance at a method too.
You can read :
http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html (a king)
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/98083/cant-i-just-use-all-static-methods
https://dzone.com/articles/why-static-bad-and-how-avoid

Comment: I go on in a new comment because of the length limitation.
Conception is often opinion-dependent. In general, I do my own idea on design. But when I am not sure and I am perplex on a matter, I like to read arguments of references in the matter such as Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

Static method should not be abused in Java.
To address your need, I propose you to take advantage of OOP : the polymorphism. 
Which will make your design more flexible and more testable.

So, you could change your static method `EmailsLogic.sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission` in an instance method . 
Then, instead of relying on static methods, you could use objects of the EmailsLogic class hierarchy.
You could create two implementations of EmailsLogic. `EmailsLogic` with the true mail sending and another class : `StubbedEmailsLogic` which extends `EmailsLogic` class  but which overrides email sending method `sendConfirmationEmailForSubmission()` by not sending mails.
Now, in your tests, use a instance of StubbedEmailsLogic which fakes the mail sending  by giving this instance to the SubmitAction class. 
Important : your action class should expect the base type `EmailsLogic`  in order to enable to switch to one or to other implementation.